# Display currency picker in header

Tags: magento

I'm trying to add currency picker in header of my magento store.
I have three currencies set and their rates are imported and saved through magentos currency manager. Here is what i've done:

**1. Edit page.xml**
I've edited `page.xml` file and added

```
<block type="directory/currency" name="currency" as="currency" template="directory/currency.phtml"/>
```

line in `header block`

**2. Edit header.phtml**
I've edited `header.phtml` file and added

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('currency') ?>
```

After those two steps, i'm not able to see currency picker in my header. I can display it in i.e. left columnt in content area but never in header. Have you any idea what am i missing ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to enable your profiler in magento and check there.

Comment: profiler is not displaying anything related to currency picker

Comment: This is my line
<block type="directory/currency" name="currency" as="currency" before="-" template="directory/currency.phtml"/> - I added before because I call it in local.xml but anyway you should see it in profiler. In addition maybe you can look in directory/currency.phtml file for errors. throw an exit there just to see if anything happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, looks like the problem was that i couldn't use the same currency block in header and in left column. All i needed to do was to change this line of `page.xml` (in header block):

```
<block type="directory/currency" name="currency" as="currency" template="directory/currency.phtml"/>
```

to

```
<block type="directory/currency" name="currency_top" as="currency_top" template="directory/currency_top.phtml"/>
```

and i offcourse clonded `directory/currency.phtml` file as `directory/currency_top.phtml`. Now currency switcher works fine. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: hi @mbajur, this code didn't work on magento2, is there any way to implement same in magento2?

Answer (score 2):

My first guess would be that your block type is wrong.

**Block Type Example**

Let's take a common block type: `page/html`.

`page` would be the module class alias. In this case we are referencing `Mage_Page_Block`.

`html` would be the class. So now we have a full block type: `Mage_Page_Block_Html`

So it's entirely possible that this is correct: we don't have enough information from you. If you have a custom module, and Company_Directory_Block_Currency exists, then that's correct after all.

My guess would be that you have a simple template (currency.phtml) that you want to render. In that case you would use the `core/template` block type. If you want to use methods that are in `Mage_Page_Block_Html` (which is probably very likely) then you will use the `page/html` block type we saw above.

**Further Trouleshooting**

Probably goes without saying, but make sure 'directory/currency.phtml' exists in the correct path.

Beyond that, enable path/template hints and make sure you are loading the current templates.

Comment: Zachary, you are wrong. The code is fine. Currency block should be type directory/currency - this means it's using that model. And the model exist in magento.

Comment: yeah, `directory/currency.phtml` exists but it's not loaded, even profiler desn't see it

Answer (score 0):

Open header.phtml and paste below code at proper place

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('directory/currency')->setTemplate('directory/currency.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Code Taken: http://chandreshrana.blogspot.in/2014/04/display-currency-selector-in-header.html